# Cosmos db cassandra api write path

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

Does cosmosdb cassandra api uses same memtable , commit log, systable compaction write path  to provide good performance for heavy write operations  or is it same as the write operations in cosmos sql api.

Will cosmos cassndra api is suppose to work better then  write same no. of write  operations in cosmos sql api?

Comment: The Cassandra API is one of several APIs available, and sits on the same core data engine. Just like the MongoDB API. There's no Cassandra ring behind-the-scenes. As for "work better" - you'd need to do your own benchmarking to measure Request Unit cost, etc.

Comment: @DavidMakogon What difference it makes while choosing different api at the time of creation itself. Because as per other blogs all cosmos apis run on core sql api. In terms of performance, storage and difference is there theoritically?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your follow-up comment. My point is simply that there is no "native Cassandra ring" running - all the APIs sit atop the same core database system. And the non-native APIs (e.g. Cassandra, MongoDB, Gremlin) are all going to ultimately translate to native database operations. And as I already stated, you will need to do your own benchmarking to see what the performance characteristics are, of your various queries.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I was trying to understand what makes a sql api and cassandra api different. I know the storage at the deepest level is same ARS . But is there a layer above it that makes storage different , Or there are different read pattern or internal node topology May be if u wnt to comment on my other questions that will be really helpful.

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345105/what-are-storage-differences-between-cosmosdb-sql-api-and-cosmosdb-cassandra-api/62347255?noredirect=1#comment110267440_62347255       2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345954/when-should-someone-choose-cosmosdb-cassandra-api-over-cosmosdb-sql-api-if-build/62347393?noredirect=1#comment110269355_62347393

Comment: So you've essentially asked the same question three times now, based on your links. I'm not going to comment on those other questions, as they are opinion-soliciting and slightly different forms of the question here.